# Create JPA Join entities Java

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jpa

I'm new at JPA stuff. I get trouble defining table joins. Can you help me?

Below is the ER Model.

How should JPA entities look like? I need CRUD operations Thanks a lot!

[image: alt]

This is DB Script:

`CREATE TABLE vidrio (
                id_vidrio INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
                grosor DOUBLE PRECISION NOT NULL,
                largo DOUBLE PRECISION NOT NULL,
                ancho DOUBLE PRECISION NOT NULL,
                precio DOUBLE PRECISION NOT NULL,
                descripcion VARCHAR (250) NOT NULL,
                PRIMARY KEY (id_vidrio)
);`

`CREATE TABLE persona (
                id_persona VARCHAR (250) NOT NULL,
                nombre VARCHAR (250) NOT NULL,
                apellido VARCHAR (250) NOT NULL,
                direccion VARCHAR (250) NOT NULL,
                ciudad VARCHAR (250) NOT NULL,
                telefono VARCHAR (250) NOT NULL,
                PRIMARY KEY (id_persona)
);`

`CREATE TABLE empleado (
                id_empleado VARCHAR (250) NOT NULL,
                id_persona VARCHAR (250) NOT NULL,
                gerente BOOLEAN NOT NULL,
                contrasena VARCHAR (250) NOT NULL,
                PRIMARY KEY (id_empleado)
);`

`CREATE TABLE factura (
                factura_id INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
                fecha DATE NOT NULL,
                id_empleado VARCHAR (250) NOT NULL,
                id_persona VARCHAR (250) NOT NULL,
                id_empleado_corte VARCHAR (250) NOT NULL,
                PRIMARY KEY (factura_id)
);`

`CREATE TABLE detalle_factura (
                factura_id INT NOT NULL,
                id_vidrio INT NOT NULL,
                PRIMARY KEY (factura_id)
);`

`CREATE TABLE cotizacion (
                cotizacion_id INT NOT NULL,
                id_empleado VARCHAR (250) NOT NULL,
                id_persona VARCHAR (250) NOT NULL,
                PRIMARY KEY (cotizacion_id)
);`

`CREATE TABLE detalle_cotizacion (
                cotizacion_id INT NOT NULL,
                id_vidrio INT NOT NULL,
                PRIMARY KEY (cotizacion_id)
);`

> DB Constraints

`ALTER TABLE detalle_factura ADD CONSTRAINT vidrio_detalle_factura_fk
FOREIGN KEY (id_vidrio)
REFERENCES vidrio (id_vidrio)
ON DELETE NO ACTION
ON UPDATE NO ACTION;`

`ALTER TABLE detalle_cotizacion ADD CONSTRAINT vidrio_detalle_cotizacion_fk
FOREIGN KEY (id_vidrio)
REFERENCES vidrio (id_vidrio)
ON DELETE NO ACTION
ON UPDATE NO ACTION;`

`ALTER TABLE empleado ADD CONSTRAINT persona_empleado_fk
FOREIGN KEY (id_persona)
REFERENCES persona (id_persona)
ON DELETE NO ACTION
ON UPDATE NO ACTION;`

`ALTER TABLE factura ADD CONSTRAINT persona_factura_fk
FOREIGN KEY (id_persona)
REFERENCES persona (id_persona)
ON DELETE NO ACTION
ON UPDATE NO ACTION;`

`ALTER TABLE cotizacion ADD CONSTRAINT persona_cotizacion_fk
FOREIGN KEY (id_persona)
REFERENCES persona (id_persona)
ON DELETE NO ACTION
ON UPDATE NO ACTION;`

`ALTER TABLE cotizacion ADD CONSTRAINT empleado_cotizacion_fk
FOREIGN KEY (id_empleado)
REFERENCES empleado (id_empleado)
ON DELETE NO ACTION
ON UPDATE NO ACTION;`

`ALTER TABLE factura ADD CONSTRAINT empleado_factura_fk
FOREIGN KEY (id_empleado)
REFERENCES empleado (id_empleado)
ON DELETE NO ACTION
ON UPDATE NO ACTION;`

`ALTER TABLE factura ADD CONSTRAINT empleado_factura_fk1
FOREIGN KEY (id_empleado_corte)
REFERENCES empleado (id_empleado)
ON DELETE NO ACTION
ON UPDATE NO ACTION;`

`ALTER TABLE detalle_factura ADD CONSTRAINT factura_detalle_factura_fk
FOREIGN KEY (factura_id)
REFERENCES factura (factura_id)
ON DELETE NO ACTION
ON UPDATE NO ACTION;`

`ALTER TABLE detalle_cotizacion ADD CONSTRAINT cotizacion_detalle_cotizacion_fk
FOREIGN KEY (cotizacion_id)
REFERENCES cotizacion (cotizacion_id)
ON DELETE NO ACTION
ON UPDATE NO ACTION;`

I'm having trouble defining JPA Entities. Also persisting Data.

Comment: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/jpa/jpa_entity_relationships.htm This link may help you.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow :-) What did you try?

Comment: @JimHawkins I tried using Netbeans generated Entities. But isn't working.

Comment: This is DB Script 
CREATE TABLE vidrio (
                id_vidrio INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
                grosor DOUBLE PRECISION NOT NULL,
                largo DOUBLE PRECISION NOT NULL,
                ancho DOUBLE PRECISION NOT NULL,
                precio DOUBLE PRECISION NOT NULL,
                descripcion VARCHAR (250) NOT NULL,
                PRIMARY KEY (id_vidrio)
);

Comment: Netbeans isn't responsible for creating beans but it's you. Don't post relevant informations in comment, it's painful to read. Please edit the question, and look at [ask] and how to create a [mcve].

Comment: @JimHawkins Sorry, I'm new at this! Just added more information at post. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Sergio. You did not give table "cotizacion" definiton. Please add.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check This.

```
**Cotizacion.java**

@Entity
@Table(name = "cotizacion")
@XmlRootElement
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "Cotizacion.findAll", query = "SELECT c FROM Cotizacion c"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Cotizacion.findByCotizacionId", query = "SELECT c FROM Cotizacion c WHERE c.cotizacionId = :cotizacionId")})
public class Cotizacion implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "cotizacion_id")
    private Integer cotizacionId;
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "cotizacion")
    private DetalleCotizacion detalleCotizacion;
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_persona", referencedColumnName = "id_persona")
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    private Persona idPersona;
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_empleado", referencedColumnName = "id_empleado")
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    private Empleado idEmpleado;

    //Getters And Settes
}

**DetalleCotizacion.java**

@Entity
@Table(name = "detalle_cotizacion")
@XmlRootElement
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "DetalleCotizacion.findAll", query = "SELECT d FROM DetalleCotizacion d"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "DetalleCotizacion.findByCotizacionId", query = "SELECT d FROM DetalleCotizacion d WHERE d.cotizacionId = :cotizacionId")})
public class DetalleCotizacion implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "cotizacion_id")
    private Integer cotizacionId;
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_vidrio", referencedColumnName = "id_vidrio")
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    private Vidrio idVidrio;
    @JoinColumn(name = "cotizacion_id", referencedColumnName = "cotizacion_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    @OneToOne(optional = false)
    private Cotizacion cotizacion;

    //Getters And Setters
}

**DetalleFactura.java**

@Entity
@Table(name = "detalle_factura")
@XmlRootElement
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "DetalleFactura.findAll", query = "SELECT d FROM DetalleFactura d"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "DetalleFactura.findByFacturaId", query = "SELECT d FROM DetalleFactura d WHERE d.facturaId = :facturaId")})
public class DetalleFactura implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "factura_id")
    private Integer facturaId;
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_vidrio", referencedColumnName = "id_vidrio")
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    private Vidrio idVidrio;
    @JoinColumn(name = "factura_id", referencedColumnName = "factura_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    @OneToOne(optional = false)
    private Factura factura;

    //Getters And Setters
}

**Empleado.java**

@Entity
@Table(name = "empleado")
@XmlRootElement
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "Empleado.findAll", query = "SELECT e FROM Empleado e"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Empleado.findByIdEmpleado", query = "SELECT e FROM Empleado e WHERE e.idEmpleado = :idEmpleado"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Empleado.findByGerente", query = "SELECT e FROM Empleado e WHERE e.gerente = :gerente"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Empleado.findByContrasena", query = "SELECT e FROM Empleado e WHERE e.contrasena = :contrasena")})
public class Empleado implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "id_empleado")
    private String idEmpleado;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "gerente")
    private boolean gerente;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "contrasena")
    private String contrasena;
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "idEmpleado")
    private Set<Cotizacion> cotizacionSet;
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "idEmpleadoCorte")
    private Set<Factura> facturaSet;
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "idEmpleado")
    private Set<Factura> facturaSet1;
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_persona", referencedColumnName = "id_persona")
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    private Persona idPersona;

    //Getters And Setters
}

**Factura.java**

@Entity
@Table(name = "factura")
@XmlRootElement
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "Factura.findAll", query = "SELECT f FROM Factura f"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Factura.findByFacturaId", query = "SELECT f FROM Factura f WHERE f.facturaId = :facturaId"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Factura.findByFecha", query = "SELECT f FROM Factura f WHERE f.fecha = :fecha")})
public class Factura implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "factura_id")
    private Integer facturaId;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "fecha")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date fecha;
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_persona", referencedColumnName = "id_persona")
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    private Persona idPersona;
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_empleado_corte", referencedColumnName = "id_empleado")
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    private Empleado idEmpleadoCorte;
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_empleado", referencedColumnName = "id_empleado")
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    private Empleado idEmpleado;
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "factura")
    private DetalleFactura detalleFactura;

    //Getters And Setters
}

**Persona.java**

@Entity
@Table(name = "persona")
@XmlRootElement
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "Persona.findAll", query = "SELECT p FROM Persona p"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Persona.findByIdPersona", query = "SELECT p FROM Persona p WHERE p.idPersona = :idPersona"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Persona.findByNombre", query = "SELECT p FROM Persona p WHERE p.nombre = :nombre"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Persona.findByApellido", query = "SELECT p FROM Persona p WHERE p.apellido = :apellido"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Persona.findByDireccion", query = "SELECT p FROM Persona p WHERE p.direccion = :direccion"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Persona.findByCiudad", query = "SELECT p FROM Persona p WHERE p.ciudad = :ciudad"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Persona.findByTelefono", query = "SELECT p FROM Persona p WHERE p.telefono = :telefono")})
public class Persona implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "id_persona")
    private String idPersona;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "nombre")
    private String nombre;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "apellido")
    private String apellido;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "direccion")
    private String direccion;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "ciudad")
    private String ciudad;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "telefono")
    private String telefono;
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "idPersona")
    private Set<Cotizacion> cotizacionSet;
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "idPersona")
    private Set<Factura> facturaSet;
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "idPersona")
    private Set<Empleado> empleadoSet;

    //Getters And Setters
}

Vidrio.java

@Entity
@Table(name = "vidrio")
@XmlRootElement
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "Vidrio.findAll", query = "SELECT v FROM Vidrio v"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Vidrio.findByIdVidrio", query = "SELECT v FROM Vidrio v WHERE v.idVidrio = :idVidrio"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Vidrio.findByGrosor", query = "SELECT v FROM Vidrio v WHERE v.grosor = :grosor"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Vidrio.findByLargo", query = "SELECT v FROM Vidrio v WHERE v.largo = :largo"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Vidrio.findByAncho", query = "SELECT v FROM Vidrio v WHERE v.ancho = :ancho"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Vidrio.findByPrecio", query = "SELECT v FROM Vidrio v WHERE v.precio = :precio"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Vidrio.findByDescripcion", query = "SELECT v FROM Vidrio v WHERE v.descripcion = :descripcion")})
public class Vidrio implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "id_vidrio")
    private Integer idVidrio;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "grosor")
    private double grosor;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "largo")
    private double largo;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "ancho")
    private double ancho;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "precio")
    private double precio;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "descripcion")
    private String descripcion;
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "idVidrio")
    private Set<DetalleCotizacion> detalleCotizacionSet;
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "idVidrio")
    private Set<DetalleFactura> detalleFacturaSet;

    //Getters And Setters
}
```

Comment: Sorry about that! Just updated DB Script! Can you please give me a simple example of how to persist M:M relationship between factura-vidrio? Thanks a lot! Your help is very useful!

Comment: Thanks a lot!! It looks pretty good! I'm trying to make it work!! I'm testing it! Just need to persist and show data!

Comment: Don't forget to Accept Answer.